# How do I show just the first image from mysql database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code.  How do I show the first image in the database with index of 0 for the large image display at end of the code?  Right now it is showing the last image in the database.

```
    <div id="imgWheel" class="treatmentContainer">
   <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = 0 ORDER BY id;";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
           while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
             $product = $row["product"];
             $room = $row["room"];
             $style = $row["style"];
             $tags = $row["tags"];
             $src = $row["url"];
             $dataid = $row["id"];
                        
              $imgClass = "";
               if (in_array($src, $favourites)) {
                   $imgClass = " favourite";
               }
                        
echo "<div class='treatment$imgClass' data-url='$src' data-product='$product' data-room='$room' data-style='$style' data-tags='$tags' data-number='$dataid' id='pic_$dataid' >";
echo "<img src='$src' crossorigin='anonymous'/>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>   
                    
</div> <!-- close imgWheel -->   

<!-------- Large Image Display------- -->

<div id="display">
     <img  id="mainImage" src="<?php echo $src ?>" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result set is alreadyx ordered by id, so you need only a variable, to be filled once with the first imageurl

```
<div id="imgWheel" class="treatmentContainer">
<?php
    $bigpictureurl = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = 0 ORDER BY id;";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
       while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $product = $row["product"];
         $room = $row["room"];
         $style = $row["style"];
         $tags = $row["tags"];
         $src = $row["url"];
         $dataid = $row["id"];
         if (empty($bigpictureurl)) {
             $bigpictureurl = $src ;
         }          
          $imgClass = "";
           if (in_array($src, $favourites)) {
               $imgClass = " favourite";
           }
                    
echo "<div class='treatment$imgClass' data-url='$src' data-product='$product' data-room='$room' data-style='$style' data-tags='$tags' data-number='$dataid' id='pic_$dataid' >";
echo "<img src='$src' crossorigin='anonymous'/>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>   
                    
</div> <!-- close imgWheel -->   

<!-------- Large Image Display------- -->

<div id="display">
     <img  id="mainImage" src="<?php echo $bigpictureurl ?>" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your SQL query, just add **LIMIT 1**. This will limit the result just to 1 record and as you have **ORDER id ASC**, it will show the first record of the  given user (as per you it is 0).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;";
```

Comment: Thank you. So do I just have to write my query statement again? Because I do want all the records.  I just need to populate the display image with the first record.   I was trying avoid having to run the script again.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to save your first image in some separate variables, for example like this:

```
$isFirst = true;
$firstImageSrc = "";
$result = ....;
while (...) {
   // set your $product, $room etc here
   if ($isFirst) {
      $isFirst = false;
      $firstImageSrc = $src;
   }
}
echo ...
?>
</div> <!-- close imgWheel -->   

<!-------- Large Image Display------- -->

<div id="display">
     <img  id="mainImage" src="<?php echo $firstImageSrc ?>" /> 
</div>
```

A much more elegant solution would be to create an array with all your images, so that you can separate your php from your html. I will refactor your code below, and fix your first image problem as well:

```
<?php
   $images = [];
   $idx = 0;
   $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = 0 ORDER BY id;";
   $result = $mysqli->query($query);
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $images[$idx]["product"] = $row["product"];
      $images[$idx]["room"] = $row["room"];
      $images[$idx]["style"] = $row["style"];
      $images[$idx]["tags"] = $row["tags"];
      $images[$idx]["src"] = $row["url"];
      $images[$idx]["dataid"] = $row["id"];

      $images[$idx]["imgClass"] = "";
      if (in_array($src, $favourites)) {
         $images[$idx]["imgClass"] = " favourite";
      }
      $idx++;
   }
?>

<div id="imgWheel" class="treatmentContainer">

<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
   <div class='treatment<?=$image["imgClass"]?>' data-url='<?=$image["src"]?>' data-product='<?=$image["product"]?>' data-room='<?=$image["room"]?>' data-style='<?=$image["style"]?>' data-tags='<?=$image["tags"]?>' data-number='<?=$image["dataid"]?>' id='pic_<?=$image["dataid"]?>' >
      <img src='<?=$image["src"]?>' crossorigin='anonymous'/>
   </div>
<?php } ?> 
                    
</div> <!-- close imgWheel -->   

<!-------- Large Image Display------- -->

<div id="display">
     <img id="mainImage" src="<?=$images[0]["src"]?>" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Teodor.  I've tried it and getting errors.  I'm fixing those like undefined for $src.  I see where you are going with this so I can work with this.

Comment: The "quick and dirty" solution worked like a charm!  I did something similar but think I had the syntax wrong for display.

Comment: Sorry for the errors, I didn't have access to an editor to do some syntax correction, wrote everything in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all of that in your `WHILE` statement, I assume you want to `echo` all those records. And then at the end show the 1st pic. So for the "Large Image Display," give this a try:

```
<div id="display">
     $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = 0;";
     $result = $mysqli->query($query);
     $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
     $src = $row["url"];
     <img  id="mainImage" src="<?php echo $src ?>" /> 
</div>
```

If you'd like less code, then save the value of `$src` inside your `WHILE` loop when `user=0` into some other variable like `$src2`. And then your code simply becomes:

```
<img  id="mainImage" src="<?php echo $src2 ?>" />
```